# Executable "dcdg" runs "bin\dcdg.dart", which was not found in dcdg

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I try to generate my UML / class diagram from my package. I've given the command : "flutter pub global activate dcdg". The final result says: "Warning: Executable "dcdg" runs "bin\dcdg.dart", which was not found in dcdg."
Please refer to the results below. What should I do to be able to create the class diagram?

```
C:\Users\srire\AndroidStudioProjects\filmseru>flutter pub global activate dcdg
Resolving dependencies...
+ _fe_analyzer_shared 31.0.0 (34.0.0 available)
+ analyzer 2.8.0 (3.2.0 available)
+ args 2.3.0
+ async 2.8.2
+ charcode 1.3.1
+ cli_util 0.3.5
+ collection 1.15.0
+ convert 3.0.1
+ crypto 3.0.1
+ dcdg 4.0.1
+ file 6.1.2
+ glob 2.0.2
+ meta 1.7.0
+ package_config 2.0.2
+ path 1.8.1
+ pub_semver 2.1.0
+ source_span 1.8.2
+ string_scanner 1.1.0
+ term_glyph 1.2.0
+ typed_data 1.3.0
+ watcher 1.0.1
+ yaml 3.1.0
Installed executable dcdg.
Warning: Executable "dcdg" runs "bin\dcdg.dart", which was not found in dcdg.
Activated dcdg 4.0.1.
```

Actually, there is no tutorial on YouTube to solve this specific problem.

Comment: What version of flutter and dart are you using? I am not certain if this will work, but try `flutter pub global deactivate dcdg` and then try running `flutter pub global activate dcdg` again. Do you still get the warning?

Comment: Im using `Flutter version 2.8.1` and `Dart version 2.15.1` , i just follow your suggestion and still got the same warning

Comment: Actually, it seems that I see the same warning when trying to use `flutter pub global activate dcdg` but no warning when using `pub global activate dcdg`.

Comment: If you run `pub global activate dcdg` are you able to activate dcdg without any warnings?  If pub is not on your path, you will need to add it to your path first. In my case it is located at `C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin` . The exact location may vary if you have installed flutter in another location. If you enter `where flutter` it should tell you where your flutter installation is.